# How do I learn the Quenya Dialect?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, languages, elves, tolkien-languages

**Quenya,** the popular Elvish language is used in all *The Lord of the Rings* books and movies and appears very beautiful due to its flowing letters and has a charismatic visual appeal.

How would I go about learning the Quenya alphabet and word definitons?
[image]

Comment: There are, however, free Quenya-English dictionaries available online and also some forums/sites that "teach" you basic Quenya. (A simple Google search will bring up the results)

Comment: That is not Quenya, it is the Black Speech; it's the inscription on the Ring. The letters are Elvish (Tengwar), but the language is definitely not.

Comment: https://folk.uib.no/hnohf/ This site has an excellent self guided course, if you have the geek cred to work your way through it!

Comment: It should also be noted Quenya does not get a lot of use in Lord of the Rings, most of the Elvish you see is actually Sindarin.